# How do I get the database value of a text field with $content?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I need to output a raw link from within a text field, without all the "field-" divs, in node.tpl. I've tried `<?php print render($content['field_download_link']['LANGUAGE_NONE']['0']['value']); ?>` but nothing displays.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install and enable [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

> A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers
>   ...

After that add to your page.tpl.php file this:

```
<?php dpm($content); ?>
```

You need to be logged in as administrator and you will see debugger on the page. Find the value you want to print and double-click on it, you will see the exact "path" to the value and just print it as you wrote in your question.

Comment: I did as you said but I'm not seeing where to double click. I enabled everything within Devel's configuration page but no field machine names are popping up anywhere.

Comment: try to double click anything form debugger (array, object, value...) and you'll see that the "path" will show...try to dpm some other variable, like $page...

Comment: Okay got it. Awesome module. So it's $...['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7533]['field_download_link']['#field_name'], is there something I can put in place of 7533 to have it affect all nodes? And how do I write it out exactly?

Comment: Insted of `$...` at the beggining, you write variable that you put in `dpm` and print that. For this I recommend you to override content type's tpl.php, not page.tpl.php (take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/17565 to see how to do that), in that file you can use `<?php dpm($node); ?>` and find the value you want to print, this will be applied to all nodes of that content type. Simply, you can copy the `node.tpl.php` file from `/modules/node/` in your Drupal root to `templates` folder of your theme, and rename it to target content type as described on link that I wrote you above...

Comment: I placed <?php dpm($node); ?> at the top of node--feed_item.tpl.php, then <?php print dpm($node['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7533]['field_download_link']['#field_nam‌​e']); ?> where I want the field, but it just causes the site to load without any css. Definitely doing this wrong. Also can I use the modified node.tpl I was using before or does it have to be a copy of the system one?

Comment: look through Theming Documentation at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme and find out more about Drupal Debugging at http://randyfay.com/debugging_drupal